# ASP.NET Web.config <runtime> element not inherited into child application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7.5

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 application created as an IIS website with its own .NET 4.0 CLR app pool and physical path at:

```
C:\Websites\XXX\Web\en-HK
```

Under this site I have a child application "zh" in IIS (another MVC5 application), again with its own .NET 4.0 CLR app pool and physical path at:

```
C:\Websites\XXX\Web\zh-Hans-HK
```

Both sites have their own web.configs, with the child one only overriding a single `<appSetting>` which is working. What is not working however is that the  element in the parent does no appear to be inherited down. The element looks like:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

When I first run the child application in a browser I see a YSOD complaining about that MVC 3.0 can't be found - this is because a 3rd party DLL is looking for MVC 3 but the binding that should redirect to 5.2 isn't there.

If I paste the `<runtime>` element into the child web.config - the error goes away.

Is the `<runtime>` element prevented from being inherited in child application by design or is my set-up off?
It doesn't appear to be protected in machine.config.

**UPDATE**

I think the issue is to do with assembly probing.

When I've enabled the assembly load trace I can see that the YSOD in the child app is caused by ELMAH's dependency on MVC3, when .NET probes the application config (my child apps web.config) it cant find any `<assemblyBinding>` info so moves on to check the *aspnet.config*, **not my parent sites web.config** which does have the `<assemblyBinding>` info.

[image]

I guess this behaviour is by design?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Asp.Net engine composes your Web.config files following IIS hierarchy into a final configuration source that the .Net runtime uses for requests within specific web locations

However, the `<runtime>` section is a bit special because it is so low level. It is not used by managed code but by the unmanaged .Net runtime *host* to define its overall behavior (assembly binding is the most common but GC related stuff and others)